# jQuery .on not recognising urls from jQuery $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, .post, jquery-post

My script below generates a url if the $.post() response has an error. I am trying to use .on() so that I can attach a function to the URL generated, but it does not work. When I add the URL in the DOM (without the $.post) it works like a charm, it just does not want to work if the url is generated within $.post(). Any ideas or solution on how I can get it working?

```
// Do the database check:
$.post("test.php",{searchFor : search},function(data) {
       if(data.response == true) {
           // DO SOME STUFF
       } else if(data.response == false && data.error == "noDoc") {
           $("#resultsTable").html("<tr><td colspan='6'><p><strong>No user found, <a href='#' class='addDoctor'>Click here</a> to add a doctor.</strong></p></tr>");
       } else {
           $("#resultsTable").html("<tr><td colspan='6'><p><strong>"+data.error+"</strong></p></tr>");
       }
   });
});

$(".addDoctor").on("click",function() {
   alert("test");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: As a side note, to test the functionality, I created a <a href='#' class='addDoctor'>LINK</a> and that does work, it just does not work if the url is added to the DOM using $.post()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.test')` in your code, searches for all elements with a class named "test" in your DOM, and adds a click listener to them. This will only affect the elements that can be found when the call to `.on` is being executed (i.e. *not* when the actual click happens).

If you are adding elements with the test class *after* the call to `.on`, you will need to call `.on` for an element that will be the parent of all your `.test` elements, and that will never be destroyed:

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

For optimal performance, select the closest possible parent, so that a smaller part of the DOM has to be searched for eligible elements. The use of `document` here is not necessarily ideal, but it is the closest I can assume, without knowing your DOM.

Comment: Hi David, I apologise for the mistake in my code with my original post. I tested the .on() on a class I created to test if it worked, and never renamed it back to .addDoctor when I pasted it here. The .addDoctor class is created within the else if statement in the 
$.post()

Comment: @Mauritz: well, your *current* code is wrong because `href="#"` in `.addDoctor` terminates the string. Replace it with `href=\"#\"`. Having fixed that, `$(document).on('click', '.doctor', callback)` should work.

Comment: I have done both and the script still goes ahead with the submission of the URL (not failing with the return false). console does not give any errors so I am beginning to think I am not using on correctly. I tried your option above $("document").on("click",".addDoctor",function() { function stuff}); but no success. Does .on() definately work with URL's added to the DOM within a $.post()?

Comment: @Mauritz: Not `$('document')`, but `$(document)`. Without the quotes. [And yes, it works with content added to the DOM after DOMReady](http://jsfiddle.net/qBvk3/)

Answer (score 0):

You might be wanting something like:

```
$(".addDoctor").on("click", function(event){
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Sorry this was a mistake in my code when I asked the question. I have changed it but same problem